# How to convert specific strings to int from dynamic json's url?

Tags: php, json

I would like to remove "" from a few strings from json which updates every few minutes (http://zergpool.com/api/status).

for example:

```
{"bitcore":{"name":"bitcore","port":3556,"coins":1,"fees":0,"hashrate":0,"workers":0,"estimate_current":"0.00001745","estimate_last24h":"0.00001756","actual_last24h":"0.00000","hashrate_last24h":105820474.1458},
```

Fields:

```
"estimate_current":"0.00001745" -> "estimate_current":0.00001745

"estimate_last24h":"0.00001756" -> "estimate_last24h":0.00001756

"actual_last24h":"0.00000" -> "actual_last24h":0.00000
```

Since the numbers change all the time, is it possible to write a PHP to convert them in real time? This is what I did.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://zergpool.com/api/status';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$manage = json_decode($data,true);

//$aha = (int)preg_replace("/[^\d]+/","",$manage); // tried removing them like this... doesn't work.

echo json_encode($manage)
```

doesn't work :(

Comment: Why do you want to cast that to number?

Comment: So, another program could read it. And, I can't change the program unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove quotes from numeric values in JSON.

```
$encoded = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Supported in the versions `>= PHP 5.3`

Comment: It's casts string to float but returns wrong values. Eg: String 0.00001745 => Float 1.745E-5

Comment: @PraneethNidarshan that's the same this answer is correct try inputting that on console it will return `0.00001745 `

Comment: <?php $num_string = "0.00001745";
$num_string = (float) $num_string;
echo ($num_string); ?> @Beginner getting the same

Comment: The fact that you get that 1.745E-5 number, is exactly why you _don't_ want to cast it to a float. If you want the number to not change, keep it as a string.

Comment: `"estimate_current":1.653e-5,"estimate_last24h":1.873e-5` I got these when echo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.ahashpool.com/api/status/");
$ar = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$filter = [];
foreach ($ar as $k => $sub_ar) {
    foreach ($sub_ar as $sub_k => $sub_v) {
        if(preg_match('/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/', $sub_v)){
            $filter[$k][$sub_k] = (float) $sub_v;
        } else {
            $filter[$k][$sub_k] = $sub_v;
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($filter);
die();
```

Comment: I notice that you have have miss one parenthesis at the last of your `JSON` string so I have added and answered it accordingly.

Comment: I want to take json from this http://zergpool.com/api/status and convert it in PHP so that double quotes "" in 'estimate_current','estimate_last24h','actual_last24h' are removed. The one I showed you guys was just a a part of it. Sorry, did explain properly.

Comment: Then you need to identified all the keys which you want to type cast from `string` to `float` and placed it in the `in_array`

Comment: I'm stuck. I can't echo them all together. Could you please give me an example maybe just 2 keys from https://www.ahashpool.com/api/status/ (Bitcore and Blake2s)? I will try to work the rest out again myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace( '"', '' ,$data);
```

will remove all the double quotes.

I don't understand why you are trying to remove the double quotes from the $manage line. You can just access the elements of the json that are returned in $manage and convert to float.

```
$firstString = $manage['bitcore']['estimate_current']; 
$firstFloat = (float)$firstString;
var_dump($firstFloat);
```

or

```
echo 'floatval=' . floatval($firstString);
```